# Запуск sopcast

Tags: ubuntu

Доброго времени суток! При запуске сопки выдает такую ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/sopcast-player.py", line 784, in <module>    pySop = pySopCast()  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/sopcast-player.py", line 89, in __init__    handler.write()  File "/usr/share/sopcast-player/lib/MimetypeHandler.py", line 38, in write    FILE.close()UnboundLocalError: local variable 'FILE' referenced before assignment
```

В чем может быть проблема?ОС Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Каких-то библиотек не хватает! Как вы sopcast устанавливали? Из сорцов, что ли? Или пакетом одинарным? В общем, поставьте необходимые библиотеки!

Comment: из репозитория ставил. libcpp скопировал. vlc 2.0 стоит.

Comment: Попробуйте убрать, и переустановить аптитьюдом (aptitude), он лучше зависимости ловит, чем apt-get. Если и так не выйдет, то это вопрос не сюда, а к тем, кто эту прогу делал! Фидбек наверное у них есть.

Comment: Немнолжечко поясню, как олдскульный программер. Если в проге идёт обращение к необъявленной переменной (это ваш случай), то значит эта переменная должна быть объявлена в какой-то библиотеке. Линковщик установил на неё внешнюю ссылку, а... Библилтеки-то и нету! Лучше всего спросить об этом у разрабов!

Answer (score 0):

Както я ставил sopcast. Описание здесь. https://plus.google.com/115298794494812842226/posts/aMH8fBAmwSh